# Question about NoResourceAvailableException in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

Here is the error message:

```
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (34/40) (95aac9e47f777ddc73c7a29cc1091911) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (35/40) (5181fb35b0a2eab588dd7ed2eb902bbd) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (36/40) (bf4aac9423bdecaeeb7e6ac37001d73d) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (37/40) (31f8ee4d7adbcfd5de21b4cbb83c5e05) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (38/40) (8ba11f69e8e5ee2aacaa276136ad3bd0) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (39/40) (1a1e38ede6b8d398b50b8fe7de2c6cb2) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:32:57,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (40/40) (7fbb095da45b2d2392874fe4fa5c916d) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2019-10-27 05:37:57,088 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Flink Streaming Job (4e5011eb97e695cfb2d05048534b097a) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
2019-10-27 05:37:57,088 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Flink Streaming Job (4e5011eb97e695cfb2d05048534b097a) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not allocate all requires slots within timeout of 300000 ms. Slots required: 152, slots allocated: 150, previous allocation IDs: []
```

my parallelism setting :

```
source : 32
flatmap : 80
sink : 40
```

Is the `jobManager` try to ask for 152 slots from `resourceManager` but rm didn't have enough slots and eventually led to failure. Can't `resourceManager` to get more slots from other `taskmanagers` when slots are not available any more?

Answer (score 1):

The number of free slots is `numberOfTaskmanagers` x `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` (e.g 75 taskmanagers with 2 slots result in 150 slots). Flink itself can't trigger any kind of dynamic scaling. All you can do is to start more task-managers manually or change the task-manager configuration and restart the task-managers.

If your taskmanager dies while the job is running you can define a restart strategy (keep in mind that you need to enable checkpoints for that):
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/task_failure_recovery.html#restart-strategies

If your taskmanagers dies and doesn't get restarted it is quite likely a yarn issue.

Comment: hi, I think the slots are enough since the error happens after the subtasks are switching from CREATED TO SCHEDULE. I think the problem is that jobManager lost connection from taskManager.

Comment: Can't you see upfront if there are enough slots available. But maybe I got your question wrong. You are running your cluster on yarn, right?

Comment: Yes. I run it on yarn and it works fine for quite a long time.

Comment: Did I get you right that the task managers got restarted from yarn? If yes check your restart strategy (see updated answer)

Comment: Did I get you right that the task managers got restarted from yarn? If yes check your restart strategy (see updated answer)

Comment: this error actually failed my job and all my taskmanagers restarted. What I'm confused is that Was the error I showed caused by losing connection to taskmanager?

Comment: All your taskmanagers restarted because of that? Do you still have the logs?

Comment: In my case, taskmanager was not started due to wrong zookeeper url.